# Is my visa's "from" date included?

Tags: visas, germany

I guess this is a very easy question for all of you. "From," date for my Germany visa says: "30-07-2018". Does that mean I can enter the country on the 30th of July? Or should I be there on the 31st of July?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enter on July 30th.  It it is valid "from" that date, not only *after* that date.

From the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412), Annex VII:

> 2. ‘FROM ... TO’ heading:
>      This heading indicates the period of the visa holder’s stay as authorised by the visa.
>
>    The date from which the visa holder may enter the territory for which the visa is valid is written as below, following the word ‘FROM’: